# My Flash site won't load in Google Chrome - any tips?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, cross-browser

I built a website in Flash (CS5/AS3) and published it to a .swf and .html file. I then uploaded to my host and tested. My site displays fine in Firefox and IE, but appears as an empty page when attempting to view in Chrome. Any tips?

Update: The site will load, but isn't visible for me until I double click in the browser window or minimize/maximize the window... The site also loads fine if I access it through a hyperlink. This one's really got me confused! Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example page where this occurs?

Comment: Check your about:plugins page to make sure you have Flash installed. Try using different versions of the Flash plugin (10.0, 10.1, 10.2) to see if it's a problem with a specific version. Also, I have seen an issue in Chrome only with SWFObject, so make sure you have the latest version of that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. Flash doesn't show in chrome until I minimize or change window size.

**UPDATE:** I changed flash embeding method to SWFObject and it helped.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html